# Unity URP strange spotlight artifacts on Android build

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, lighting, urp

I've run into an issue where the spotlight for my scene has started to display some banding-like visual artifacts:

Artifact shown:

[image: Artifact shown]

Another example of artifacting:

[image: Another example of artifacting]

This issue displayed is on Unity 2022.3.5f1 and URP 14.

This effect only occurs when building to android and when the outer spot angle of the spotlight is low, and the detail of the spotlight seems to increase with the angle of the spotlight:

Larger spotlight angle artifact:

[image: Larger spotlight angle artifact]

But for my use, I require a small angle spotlight, so I was wondering if anyone else has run into this problem before and knows of a fix or workaround. This issue doesn't occur in URP 10 and seems to be only present in later updates, so I feel it has something to do with light cookies that have been added to spotlights in later versions.

I've tried messing around with all the quality, player, and graphics project settings. I've looked at banding fixes like using the 32-bit display buffer, I've looked at the lighting settings, and I've tried editing the spotlight variables in debug mode. Sadly, none of these changes managed to fix the issue.

This is what I want the spotlight to look like at the lower angle (image from windows build):

[image: What the spotlight should look like]

Comment: its [shadow acne](https://digitalrune.github.io/DigitalRune-Documentation/html/3f4d959e-9c98-4a97-8d85-7a73c26145d7.htm) change the shadow bias of your light

Comment: @Jay Thank you for the comment, shadow acne is only produced by casting shadows, this spotlight is not casting shadows nor is the object receiving any. Making it cast shadows and changing the biases doesn't seem impact the artifacts. This issue seems to be tied to how the light is being produced in the newer versions of URP.